# Is there any possible way to create object name to ArrayList automatically in java?

Tags: java

If it is how to pass string value as an object name to the ArrayList .

```
            int count = 0;
            String con= "contact"; 
            String generate = Integer.toString(count++);    

            String contacts = con.concat(generate);

             ArrayList<Long> // how ? // = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: What are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  can you tell me how can i solve this ?

Comment: Use [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect) maybe???

Comment: @AbishekManoharan reflection doesn't have effect on the names of the local variables used inside a method. So, what OP asks is *impossible*. Another alternative you have would be using a `Map<String, List<Long>> mapOfVariables` where you store the *name* of the variable as key and the `List<Long>` as value of an entry of this map.

Comment: Using classes and instances that you don't know at compile time requires the Reflection API.  But more to the point, Reflection is the solution of last resort for almost any computing problem.  For your use case, using Reflection would indicate bad design on your part much more than a problem with the Java environment.  There is almost certainly a way to solve your problem without Reflection.

Comment: @EvanKnowles Actually i using hash map for storing name as key and phone no as value . i want to store multiple value to a key i defined array list and passed the object to value part in hash map . i want to initilize object name dynamically to every key in the hash map . So here made this code .  getting error when i pass the string variable "contacts" as arraylist object name

Comment: @Mohanraj No, you can't use a string variable as an object name.  You can call `map.get("contacts")`, but that's as close as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create variables like that at runtime, but you could maintain a map of key/value pairs:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Long> > contactLists = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Long> >();

// Now add each contact list to the map
int count = 0;
String generate = Integer.toString(count++);    
String key = "contact" + generate;

ArrayList<Long> currentContactList = new ArrayList<Long>();
contactLists.put(key, currentContactList);

// To get the contact list back...
ArrayList<Long> myContactList = contactLists.get("contact0");
```